# TYPO3 now supports categories natively. What about tags?

Tags: typo3, tagging, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x, categorization

Since version 6 TYPO3 supports categories. Is it also possible to tag pages natively (or even content elements) or do I have to employ an extension for that?

Comment: You can simply use categories as tags, because any category can be assigned to any record. Also more, than one category, can be assigned to a record.

Comment: Hi [@viktor-livakivskyi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2070270/viktor-livakivskyi), so it's fair to say, that categories could be used as a workaround but TYPO3 doesn't support tagging natively? Handling categories as tags is rather cumbersome from an editor's standpoint.

Comment: afaik, yes. However, there is an experimental extension, made by quite known T3 ext developer (Tim Lochmüller), called [tagger](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tagger). So, you may try to play with it and contact author, if you have any ideas to improve it.